# Prolog: How to get the vertex with distance = n?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog. I was trying to solve the following problem.
There are 6 vertices in a simple graph with some edges. The facts are:

```
edge(v1, v2).
edge(v1, v6).
edge(v2, v3).
edge(v2, v4).
edge(v3, v4).
edge(v4, v5).
edge(v5, v6).
```

I am trying to get the logic of the predicate if there is an N length path between vertex U and some vertex V

```
path(U, V, N)
```

For example path(v1, V, 2) will return

```
v3
v4
v5
```

I can make predicate like (if N = 2, 3 ... )

```
path(U, V):- edge(U, X), edge(X, V).
path(U, V):- edge(U, X), edge(X, Y), edge(Y, V).
...
```

But what about path(U, V, N)?

Comment: Is this a directed graph? While your example `path(v1, V, 2)` requires it, your `path(U, V)`  contradicts it.

Comment: Yes, It is a directed graph. My notation path(U, V) is a separate predicate where N is not an argument. But it is assumed. If I assume N = 2, I will write path(U, V):- edge(U, X), edge(X, V).  If I assume N = 3, path(U, V):- edge(U, X), edge(X, Y), edge(Y, V).   But here I can not solve the path(U, V, N), where N is an input argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path(U, V, 2) :-
    edge(U, X), edge(X, V).

path(U, V, N) :-
    edge(U, X), path(X, V, N1), plus(N1, 1, N).
```

```
?- path(v1, V, 2).
V = v3 ;
V = v4 ;
false.
```

There is no path from v1 to v5 of length 2 since the graph is directed.